# Excel Vba: Creating loop that checks if the values in column A matches and copy all the rows to a new spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel

I need to select all the rows in column A that have the same the value and paste them to a new spreadsheet named with the copied name.

[image]

In the example picture when I run macro and  input value Banana I should get all the rows that contain banana in column A.

I found following vba code from the internet and tried to modify it to my needs but I'm stuck:

```
Sub LookForAllSameValues()

   Dim LSearchRow As Integer
   Dim LCopyToRow As Integer

   On Error GoTo Err_Execute

   'Start search in row 4
   LSearchRow = 2

   'Start copying data to row 2 in Sheet2 (row counter variable)
   LCopyToRow = 2

   Uname = InputBox("Test")
   ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add.Name = Uname

   While Len(Range("A" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value) > 0

      'If value in column E = "Mail Box", copy entire row to Sheet2
      If Range("A" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = Uname Then

         'Select row in Sheet1 to copy
         Rows(CStr(LSearchRow) & ":" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Select
         Selection.Copy

         'Paste row into Sheet2 in next row

         Sheets(Uname).Select
         Rows(CStr(LCopyToRow) & ":" & CStr(LCopyToRow)).Select
         ActiveSheet.Paste

         'Move counter to next row
         LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1

         'Go back to Sheet1 to continue searching
         Sheets("Sheet1").Select

      End If

      LSearchRow = LSearchRow + 1

   Wend

   'Position on cell A3
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
   Range("A3").Select

   MsgBox "All matching data has been copied."

   Exit Sub

Err_Execute:
   MsgBox "An error occurred."

End Sub
```

This code almost works. It asks user to input string to search and then it creates a new worksheet named as this one. The problem lies in the loop, I debugged the code and for some reason it just skips copy paste loop

How do I get the loop working?

Output when the code is run:

[image]

Comment: You want to copy the entire row with value right?

Comment: Yes, whole row. I Add example to my question

Comment: it may be as simple as case... replace `Range("A" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = Uname` with `StrComp(Range("A" & LSearchRow),Uname, vbTextCompare) = 0`

Comment: Hi. It still skips the loop. While Len(Range("A" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value) > 0   If StrComp(Range("A" & LSearchRow), Uname, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then

Comment: May you try to modify your init value of `LSearchRow`, it start from `A2`, but your data start from `A3`, moreover, it will skip the loop when it don't have value: `A2 = ""`

Comment: Just use Autofilter method. Then copy visible only cells. Forget about looping.

Comment: @L42 In my excel file I've over 100 different values in column A. I used fruit array as an example.

Comment: Yeah, look at my sample post. That basically does what you described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're testing this on the data shown above.

Your code states that `LSearch Row = 2` and therefore your search will begin in cell A2. I'd therefore assume your loop is never executing because `Len(Range("A2"))` equals `0` (the cell is empty) and the loop immediately exits. This also means that if any cell in column A is empty the loop will end there even if there is more data below it.

Instead try using a `For..Next` loop as shown below which will run from row 2 to the last used row in the active sheet, regardless of the cell contents.

```
Public Sub FindAndCreateNew()
    Dim strFind As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim wsFind As Worksheet
    Dim wsPaste As Worksheet

    'Get value to search for
    strFind = InputBox("Test")

    'Create object reference to the current worksheet
    Set wsFind = ActiveSheet

    'Create a new worksheet with object reference and then rename it
    Set wsPaste = Worksheets.Add
    wsPaste.Name = strFind

    'Paste starting at row 2 in wsPaste
    j = 2

    'Start searching from row 2 of wsFind, continue to end of worksheet
    For i = 2 To wsFind.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If wsFind.Range("A" & i) = strFind Then
            'Copy row i of wsFind to row j of wsPaste then increment j
            wsFind.Range(i & ":" & i).Copy Destination:=wsPaste.Range(j & ":" & j)
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

P.S. It's also worth noting that the use of `.Select` is generally avoidable and it can slow the program down considerably as well as making it less readable. For example this:

```
'Select row in Sheet1 to copy
Rows(CStr(LSearchRow) & ":" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Select
Selection.Copy
```

Could be represented with just one statement as below:

```
'Select row in Sheet1 to copy
Rows(CStr(LSearchRow) & ":" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Copy
```

Answer (score 1):

As commented, try this:

```
Sub test()
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim uname As String

    Set sh1 = Sheet1: uname = InputBox("Input")
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With

    If Len(uname) = 0 Then MsgBox "Invalid input": Exit Sub
    Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(after:= _
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
    On Error Resume Next
    sh2.Name = uname: If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox "Data already copied": _
        sh2.Delete: Exit Sub
    On Error GoTo 0

    With sh1
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        Set rng = .Range("A1", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        rng.AutoFilter 1, uname
        On Error Resume Next
        rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy sh2.Range("A1")
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox "Data not found" _
            Else MsgBox "All matching data has been copied"
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: VBA says that object is missing. Anyway thanks for the help :)

Comment: @Developous Of course you have to change the sheet name to suit.

Comment: Yes and modify so that it always creates a new sheet, when the macro is ran.

Comment: @Developous Yeah, modified it as such.